# React MUI tooltip bigger arrow

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

I'm trying to achieve bigger tooltip arrow using Material UI v4. I saw workaround for react-tooltip library using css property `border-width`. Is there any workaround for MUI tooltip arrow?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override two style classes.

If overriding `popperArrow` class, styles apply to the Popper component if `arrow={true}` and if overriding `arrow` class, styles apply to arrow element when overriding `arrow` class.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  popperArrow: arrowGenerator(),

  arrow: {
    width: 24,
    height: 17, /* = width / sqrt(2) = (length of the hypotenuse) */,
  }
});

export default function ArrowTooltips() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Tooltip title="Add" arrow classes={classes}>
      <Button>Arrow</Button>
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

Function `arrowGenerator` is defined to apply different styles based on the placement of the Tooltip.

```js
function arrowGenerator() {
  return {
    '&[x-placement*="bottom"] $arrow': {
      marginTop: -17
    },
    '&[x-placement*="top"] $arrow': {
      marginBottom: "-0.71em"
    },
    '&[x-placement*="right"] $arrow': {
      marginLeft: "-0.71em"
    },
    '&[x-placement*="left"] $arrow': {
      marginRight: "-0.71em"
    }
  };
}
```

To have the best result you need to set `margin` values in this function according to the values you set for `width` and `height` when overriding `arrow` class.

Say you set `placement="bottom"` prop on your component, in `'&[x-placement*="bottom"] $arrow':` you need to set `marginTop` to the minus value of height you set for your arrow.

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Reference: [Tooltip file](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v4.12.4/packages/material-ui/src/Tooltip/Tooltip.js)

Comment: Looks like when tooltip `placement="bottom"` and top arrow points wrong direction. For better understanding my goal is https://imgur.com/a/7vCMLNs

Comment: @SoLow Placement is for the tooltip not the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fontSize in the style of the arrow. like this:

`"& .MuiTooltip-arrow": { fontSize: "large"}`